# UITabBar opacity and overlap content

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I've added a tab bar controller to my app delegate. In IB, I adjusted the alpha property and unchecked opaque, however in the simulator I get transparency over a white background, even though there should be content below it.

Perhaps, the containing View needs to be resized to the full dimensions of the screen? I'm using a nav controller with a tableview in this tab bar item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What? You want your UITabBar to be translucent? A UITabBar is not a subclass of UINavigationBar, therefore the content from any view controllers the tab controller manages will not appear under the tab bar, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes. I could have sworn i've seen apps that do it. What are the circumstances where I can get the effect?